# Angular 2 + web3 Multiple anonymous defines in module

Tags: angular, angular2-services, ethereum

I started a project with Angular 2. So far it went ok - with help of the tutorial. Right now I have a problem with 3rd party modules (probably not Angular 2 specific problem...)
I get the following Error when trying to add web3 as a module:

```
Error: Multiple anonymous defines in module http://localhost/ethereum/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.js(…)
```

It seems like it is not compatible?! I installed it through npm. Is there a "common" way to overcome that issue?
I found some stuff ([Multiple anonymous defines in module Typescript with Riot-ts (Riotjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650736/multiple-anonymous-defines-in-module-typescript-with-riot-ts-riotjs)) with the solution:

```
/// <amd-module name="ModuleName"/>
```

No idea if it's the same problem or totally different. Top solution does not explain much...

Any hints?